# Site is preventing me from loading it's content in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have downloaded stackoverflow's index page as a sample to show it in my web project. In this project I have an IFrame in which I show the page's contents but the source is preventing me to show it in IFrame. Now I have 2 questions:

1. How can I overcome this problem? (Note: I don't want to show stackoverflow.com in an IFrame so there's no security problems for this site).
2. Is there a better way to show a HTML page inside another one?

Thank you.

Comment: Do the links need to be live? Why not just show a screenshot?

Comment: What do you mean, the source is preventing me to show it in an IFrame?

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo: I can't do that. It's not what I want. @Richard: It shows a dialog box, when I click it, it breaks out of the IFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this PHP function to remove any javascript from the page's source:

```
function strip_javascript($filter, $allowed=0){
                if(($allowed&1) == 0) // 1   href=...
                    $filter = preg_replace('/href=([\'"]).*?javascript:.*?\\1/i', "'", $filter);

                if(($allowed&2) == 0) // 2   <script....
                    $filter = preg_replace("/<script.*?>.*?<\/script>/i", "", $filter);

                if(($allowed&4) == 0) // 4   <tag on.... ---- useful for onlick or onload
                    $filter = preg_replace("/<(.*)?\son.+?=\s*?(['\"]).*?\\2/i", "<$1", $filter);
                return $filter;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use curl to fetch the contents of a url and display it ...

Comment: I have the content in my database. I just want to show it in an IFrame.